# Next.js + bootstrap 5 – manually close the modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, next.js, bootstrap-5

I'm using bootstrap 5.2 modals in my application on Next.js. I need to close the modal window after a successful back request.
I open the modal with attribute data-bs-toggle="modal"
Using the documentation and other information, I created a function in my component:

```
 export function LoginModal() {
    const loginModalRef = useRef();

    const hideModal = () => {
        const { Modal } = require("bootstrap");
        const myModal = new Modal(loginModalRef.current);

        console.log(1,myModal,Modal)
        myModal.hide();
    };

   function sendRequest() {
        // if response success
        hideModal();
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div ref={loginModalRef} id="login-modal" className="modal fade">
                <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                    <div className="modal-content">
                      <svg className="close-icon position-absolute pointer" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
                            <use xlinkHref="/images/sprite.svg#close-icon"></use>
                        </svg>
                        <div className="modal-body">
                            MyModalContetn
                            <div onClick={sendRequest}>Send</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

The hide() method does not work, the modal window remains open and no errors

Bootstrap is plugged into _app.js

```
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
    // including bootstrap js
    useEffect(() => {
        require("bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js");
    }, []);
/////
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong and how it should work in my case? Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

From the [Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/javascript/#usage-with-javascript-frameworks):

> While the Bootstrap CSS can be used with any framework, the Bootstrap JavaScript is not fully compatible with JavaScript frameworks like React, Vue, and Angular [...]. Both Bootstrap and the framework may attempt to mutate the same DOM element, resulting in bugs like dropdowns that are stuck in the “open” position.
> A better alternative for those using this type of frameworks is to use a framework-specific package instead of the Bootstrap JavaScript.

In your case this framework package would be [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/).